# Creating a vector with unique observations from a variable in Stata

Tags: loops, matrix, stata, frequency

What I am mainly trying to do is to create a variable in which I can assign, within a stratum of my sample (defined by an 'id' variable, for instance), a name that is associated with the highest frequency (in the stratum) of this same name in another (string) variable. If `tabulate`* would work the way I need it to work, my code would run like this:

```
gen new_class_within_id=""

forvarlues i=1/80 {
      tab class_var, matcell(x) if id==`i'
      svmat x
      sum x2
      local name =x1 if x2==r(max)
      replace new_class_within_id=`name' if id==`i'
}
```

That would be the general idea if `tabulate` would permit storing the unique observation names in a matrix -- the code might have some unintended errors too, of course. But while it does not seem to be possible using the above code, I thought that I could use `mkmat` if I would be able to store, in the loop, the unique observations inside a vector with some additional coding. Would that be possible? Also, is there an easier way to perform what I want to do?

*Firstly, I thought that using `tabulate` and extracting the results into a matrix would do the work that I need, but `tabulate` does not allow me to extract the names of the observations, just the frequencies. `tabulate` seemed nice because in its output it shows the unique observations of a variable in a column, but I could not find a way to extract those observations the way the output shows.

Comment: "Unique" observations according to a common dictionary definition occur just once. I suggest that the term "distinct" is better here. Further, observations in Stata don't have names; they have values in particular variables and they have observation numbers depending on the current sort order, but not names.

Comment: Just to flag that this permits a concise summary in statistical terms: you want to determine modes. Here we happily allow modes to mean modes of string variables too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand your question, but maybe I don't. Some code:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
id str1 anothvar
1 a
1 a
1 a
1 b
1 m
2 c
2 c
2 m
2 a
2 z
end

list, sepby(id)

*-----

bysort id anothvar : gen count = _N
bysort id (count): gen newvar = anothvar[_N]

list, sepby(id)
```

More work needs to be done if you have missings and/or ties.

Comment: That seems exactly what I need! Thank you!

Comment: Additionally, there is a standard statistical name for the most frequent value. It is, as you know, the mode. The `egen` function `mode()` puts modes into a new variable and works with string variables too. So `egen newvar = mode(anothvar), by(id)` gets you there in one.

Comment: Note that `mode()` has other machinery too for coping with missings and ties. It ignores missings by default.